# NullPointerException with OnTouchListener on appcompat v21

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I am trying to port my app to appcompat v21.
I have fixed my gradle file, and my themes are inherited from the appcompat themes.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final SharedPreferences touch_prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); //allows preferences to be accessed in the fucntion
       setPassword();


    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.multiscreen, menu);

    final Button decodeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decodeButton); //getting the decode button
    decodeButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { //setting the touchlistener for the button
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { //ontouch listener so we can perform actions while the button is held down
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageOutput); //so we can set the text of message output
            EditText message_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEdit); //gets the message thing
            EditText pass_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passEdit); //gets the password thing
            TextView decode_hint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHint);
            decoder decode = new decoder(); //new instance of classes
            ran verify = new ran(); //new instance of ran class
            boolean legal; //boolean variable that will indicate whether the function should proceed or not

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    legal = verify.verifyString(message_input); //checks to see if message is aight
                    if (!legal) { //stops function if message contains unsupported characters
                        illegalCharacter(verify.illegal_character);
                    }
                    else if (legal) { //allows functions to proceed if the message is ok
                        s_output = decode.decode_message(message_input, pass_input);
                        decode_hint.setText(R.string.decode_hint_prompt);

                        if (touch_prefs.getBoolean("instaclear_checkbox", true)) { //checking prefs
                            pass_input.setText("");
                        }
                        if (touch_prefs.getBoolean("clear_message_checkbox", true)) { //checking prefs
                            message_input.setText("");
                        }
                        text.setText(s_output); //displays the decoded string
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        if (touch_prefs.getBoolean("passpeek_checkbox", true)) { //checking preferences
                            text.setText("");
                            decode_hint.setText("");
                        }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

This is the part that is returning an error. The error shows a NullPointerException on this line:

```
decodeButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
```

my xml for the layout/fragment is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".multiscreen">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="@string/password_text"
        android:maxLength="500"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/clearMessage" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/messageEdit"
        android:hint="@string/message_hint"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passEdit"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:maxLength="8000"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/clearMessage" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/decode_text"
        android:id="@+id/decodeButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messageEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textHint"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/encodeButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/messageOutput"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textHint"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clear_text"
        android:id="@+id/clearMessage"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/messageEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messageEdit"
        android:onClick="clearMessage"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/passEdit"
        android:text="@string/clear_text"
        android:id="@+id/clearPassword"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/clearMessage"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/clearMessage"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/messageEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/passEdit"
        android:onClick="clearPassword"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/encode_text"
        android:id="@+id/encodeButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messageEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="message_encode" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the setcontent portion:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiscreen);
}
```

Comment: for handling click event on menu button you shoud use `onOptionsItemSelected`. But you can try final Button decodeButton = (Button) menu.findViewById(R.id.decodeButton); //getting the decode button

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing this as an `OnTouchListener` rather than enabling/disabling the button based on a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) added via [EditText.addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))?

Comment: This usually occurs when there is no view with the specified ID in the layout. Can you include the setContentView() portion of your onCreate() as well as the XML layout that you're using?

Comment: @alanv I have added those two things to the post

Comment: @ianhanniballake I want to perform an action while the button is held down and then another action when the button is released, but when a checkboxoption is ticked in preferences, the action is not performed while the button is held down

Comment: @Pr38y This is not a menu button, this is a normal button in the layout

Answer (score 0):

`decodeButton` is null because it's not found in whatever class you're working with. Get your layout (`rel_layout`), and then do `layout.findViewById` since `decodeButton` is a child of `rel_layout`.

I probably wouldn't do this in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, but instead wherever you are inflating your layout.

```
View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rel_layout, null);
Button decodeButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.decodeButton);
decodeButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
```